# Does Cinnamon Bun have brain damage?

Tags: adventure-time

In 'The Enchiridion', Cinnamon Bun attempts to do a flip but instead bumps his head.

From that point on, Cinnamon Bun appears to act 'off' as though he isn't all there.

A lot of the evidence for his potential brain damage is listed on this [wikia](http://adventuretime.wikia.com/wiki/Cinnamon_Bun) page, for adventure time, but I'm not certain of this theory.

On the one hand, we don't see a great deal of Cinnamon Bun prior to the incident, and I'm not familiar with the change in peoples behaviour from brain damage.

Is his behaviour prior to the incident 'realistic' for brain damage?

Comment: I feel like you might have better luck on a site dedicated to mental health - Cognitive Science, maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe that there was any brain damage to CB in the 'The Enchiridion'. Later on, in 'The Other Tarts', Princess Bubblegum refers to him as "half-baked". That leads me to believe that his behavior is the result of a mistake on Princess Bubblegum's part while she was creating him (similar to the problems she had in creating the Earl of Lemongrab or Goliad), rather than brain damage from his failed stunt.

This is later confirmed in 'The Red Throne' where we see CB get burned a bit, which finishes his baking.  At the end of the episode, his manner of talking has drastically changed due to this.

Answer (score 0):

But I think it is brain damage because his voice changed from that episode and even his eye color changed after that back flip

Comment: Do you have a comparison image?

Answer (score 0):

A few minutes after that happens, after Finn and Jake go through the door to get the Enchiridion, Finn falls over a log and hits his head. Jake jokingly says, “Did you get brain damage?”, it would seem as if Jake knew Cinnamon Bun had brain damage as there is no way Jake's joke that Finn got brain damage, shortly after Cinnamon Bun did is a coincidence.